# Dynamic array implementation

Tags: c, array

I would like to use code below for general purpose dynamic array implementation in my future code. How does it look?

**`array.h:`**

```
#include <stdlib.h>

/* This file describes structures and functions
   for general purpose dynamic array.
*/

struct array {
    void *data;       /* Points to where the data is */
    int numElements;  /* Number of elements */
    int sizeElem;     /* Size of a single elements */
    int capacity;     /* Current total space in number of elements */
};

/* macros for accessing array internals */
#define array_index(ARRAY, INDEX) (void *)((unsigned)((ARRAY)->data)+(INDEX*((ARRAY)->sizeElem)))
#define array_len(ARRAY) (ARRAY)->numElements
#define array_cap(ARRAY) (ARRAY)->capacity

static inline void array_init(struct array *arr, int capacity, int sizeElem) {
    arr->data = malloc(capacity * sizeElem);
    arr->capacity = capacity;
    arr->sizeElem = sizeElem;
    arr->numElements = 0;
}

/* Add an element to array. Expand array if necessary. */
static inline void array_add(struct array *arr, void *data) {
    if (arr->capacity <= arr->numElements) {
        int new_capacity = 2 * arr->capacity;
        arr->data = realloc(arr->data, new_capacity * arr->sizeElem);
        arr->capacity = new_capacity;
    }
    memcpy(array_index(arr,arr->numElements), data, arr->sizeElem);
    arr->numElements++;
}

/* Macro for traversing array elements. */
#define array_for_each(TYPE, ELEM, ARRAY) \
    for (TYPE *ELEM=(ARRAY)->data; (ELEM - (TYPE *)(ARRAY)->data) < (ARRAY)->numElements; ELEM++)


/* Removes the element at given index and moves other elements if necessary. */
static inline void array_delete_index(struct array *arr, int index) {
    int movables = arr->numElements - index - 1;
    memcpy(array_index(arr, index),
           (void *)((unsigned)array_index(arr, index) + arr->sizeElem),
           movables * arr->sizeElem);
    arr->numElements--;
}

/* If array capacity is too much compared to number of elements,
   reduce array capacity
*/
static inline void array_free_capacity(struct array *arr) {
    if (arr->capacity > 2*arr->numElements) {
        int new_capacity = arr->capacity / 2;
        arr->data = realloc(arr->data, new_capacity * arr->sizeElem);
        arr->capacity = new_capacity;
    }
}

/* Probably useless macro */
#define array_free(ARRAY) free((ARRAY)->data)

/* Search for an element and return an index if found. Otherwise, return -1
   Comparison function should return 0 if two items should be considered equal.
*/
static inline int array_search(struct array *arr, void *target, int (*cmp)(void *first, void *second)) {
    for(int i=0; i<arr->numElements; i++) {
        if(cmp(array_index(arr, i), target) == 0) return i;
    }
    return -1;
}

/* Returns a pointer to the element at given index, if it doesn't
    exist, return NULL
*/
static inline void *array_get_index(struct array *arr, int index) {
    if (index > (arr->numElements - 1)) return NULL;
    return array_index(arr, index);
}
```

How the code is used:

First you initialize the array with a data type and the initial array capacity, measured in the number of elements that the array can hold.

After that, the functions in `array.h` can be used to add, remove, traverse the array, and more.

Example:

```
struct task {
    char *task_name;
    int task_id;
};

struct array my_tasks;
/* Define an dynamic array of struct tasks */
array_init(&my_tasks, 2, sizeof(struct task));
```

Answer (score 2):

Some good practices:

## Assert on NULL parameter

Whenever you have a function passing an `array` you should either do a runtime check to see if it's `NULL` or do an `assert(array)`. To catch bugs where a `NULL` array is passed to the functions.

## Check return values for alloc functions

You should always make sure you get a non-`NULL` result from any allocation, `malloc`, `realloc` and such to fail gracefully, or at least `exit(1)` with a nice `out of memory` message. Good for catching bugs where accidentally an uninitialized count value is passed to an allocating function.

## Check for negative input

Since for instance your `numElements` is an `int` instead of `size_t` you should either change it, or at least check for negative values.

## Deleting many values

I don't know how common a use case this would be, but since on each delete, you might move a large chunk of values. Adding a function that either takes a list of indices to delete and do it in one go, by simply refilling the array with those indices excluded. Otherwise iterating over and deleting values can be a huge operation depending on the size of the array.

## Destroy function

I agree with this comment:

```
/* Probably useless macro */
#define array_free(ARRAY) free((ARRAY)->data)
```

This should be a function that both resets the `numElements = 0`, `capacity = 0` and does the `free(array->data)` as well as `array->data = NULL`.

This ensures that any reuse of the array will still result in a reallocation and hence not writing to `free`d memory. However please note that `array_add` in this case must check that `capacity > 0` and at least set it to `1`, otherwise the `realloc` will be `0`.